# $\int_a^b f(x,y) dy$ is measurable

Tags: real-analysis

$\int_a^b f(x,y) dy$ is measurable if for each $y, f(x,y)$ is measurable and for each $x, f(x,y)$ is integrable.

I am trying to proof it by showing $\{x: \int_a^b (f(x,y)-\lambda) dy>0\}$ is measurable for each $\lambda$. But I have no idea to proceed.

Comment: I would try to prove the statement for simple functions, and after try to generalize to any integrable function

Comment: @Masacroso I have no idea on how to understand the measurability of $\sum \alpha_{(x,i)} \chi_{[a_{x,i}, a_{x,i+1}](y)}$ for each $y$

Comment: sums and point-wise a.e. limits of measurable functions are measurable, so everything reduces to show that the map $x\mapsto \int\mathbf{1}_{A}(x,y) dy$ is measurable, for any chosen measurable $A\subset \mathbb{R}^2$

Comment: For non-negative $f$, this is part of Tonelli's theorem. Then write $f = f_+ - f_-$.